# Is it possible to re-raise an ActiveRecord::Rollback exception from inside a transaction block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, rollback

In my rails app, I have a transaction block in a controller's create action in which I attempt to create two records.

```
def create
  ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
    @foo = Foo.new(params[:foo].except(:bar))
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless @foo.save
    @bar = Bar.new(params[:foo][:bar])
    raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless @bar.save
  end
end
```

I'd like to be able to rescue from the Rollback so I can return an error indicating which save failed.

```
rescue ActiveRecord::Rollback => e
  @foo.errors = e if @foo.errors.blank?
ensure
  respond_with @foo
end
```

However, I never get into the rescue block. I assume this is because, as the rails documentation states, the transaction block eats the Rollback exception and doesn't re-raise it. Is there a way to force this exception to be re-raised?

Comment: Why not just raise your own exception?

Comment: I want to perform a rollback. Can I do that without the use of ActiveRecord::Rollback?

Comment: ok, updated my answer on your other question, so you do not have to rely on exceptions for normal program flow...

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this question. The answer @m_x is referring to is found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13621053.